# How to disable SharePoint Online file sharing email warnings?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

We have disabled the feature that users can share files to other users or external contacts in SharePoint Online. But sometimes they do send a link of a file to a colleague, if they are sure that the recipient colleague already has rights to open the file.

The action they do is opening Outlook (the real app and not webmail), creating a new mail, choosing *add attachment* to attach a file, choosing a file from the SharePoint document library, and clicking the add button. Outlook detects that this is a SharePoint file, and attaches a special link to the e-mail with a cloud icon on it.

Not the whole file is attached, but a link to the file in SharePoint. Great, the colleague always opens the newest version!

But, as soon as the user sends the e-mail to a colleague (even if that colleague has sufficent rights in SharePoint to open the file), the sender immediately receives a warning email from "Microsoft Outlook" (with some random e-mail addresses) with the following text:

> You don't have permission to give others access to this file. The
>   message was sent, but the following people **might** not be able to access
>   the attachment: *t.user@contoso.com* You could try:
>
> - Asking the file  owner to give the recipients permission to access the file.
> - Sending
>     the file as an attachment instead of a link.

**The question is:**

How to disable these warning e-mails? We don't want Office365 to send these anymore since they are confusing for our users.

Comment: This question has also been posted here by someone else. https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/17757217-outlook-2016-attach-sharepoint-file-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in recent office update (channel 1702):

Current Channel

March 9, 2017
Version 1702 (Build 7870.2020)
Outlook: Feature updates
This channel release contains the following feature updates:

Background removal: Remove a picture background with a free-form drawing tool.

**Check access to shared files: Outlook tells the user ahead of time if recipients may not be able to access an attached OneDrive or SharePoint file, and suggests how to fix the issue.**

Set permissions on attachments: For OneDrive or SharePoint attachments, the user can set whether recipients, in the organization or externally, have read or edit permissions to the attachment.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mt465751.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396